# How can I pull every new incoming data to api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, roblox

When a new data comes to this API, I want to send it with webhook, but I don't know how to do it exactly.

api: https://search.roblox.com/catalog/json?SortType=3&ResultsPerPage=1&CreatorID=1

Comment: Could you please give us a little more insight into exactly what you are trying to accomplish? As far as I am aware there is no easy way to monitor an "API" that you don't own, unless you want to run a server that is constantly checking for updates or something similar.

Comment: yes i am constantly trying to detect new updates, api is not mine

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.